# cant retrieve content and postId at the same time

Tags: java, android, firebase

I managed to display the users' posts in my recyclerview.
Now I want to open this post on another activity by clicking. Then I would like to be able to comment on this post.

So I tried to program this procedure.

The problem in my code is, that when I try to intent the PostId to the activity, the content of the post is no longer sent to this activity, so no content is displayed on the activity. It is not possible with this code to send Post ID and the content of the post to my activity(see comments in the code).

How should I design the code that I can receive the content and the post ID of the post?

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>{

    List<Post> list;
    Activity context;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public PostAdapter(Activity context, List<Post> list){
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void initViews(){
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.each_post, parent, false);
        initViews();
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post post = list.get(position);
        holder.setpostContent(post.getContent());

        long milliseconds = post.getTime().getTime();
        String date = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(milliseconds)).toString();
        holder.setDate(date);

        String userId = post.getUser();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    String user = task.getResult().getString("name");

                    holder.setUser(user);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,  task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });

        //Here i tried to intent the postId to my new Activity

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, OpenNewPostActivity.class);
                String postId = post.PostId;
                intent.putExtra("postid", postId);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView postTime, postContent, username;
        View view;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            view.setOnClickListener(v -> openPost());
        }

        public void setpostContent(String content){
            postContent = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_new_post_text);
            postContent.setText(content);
        }

        public void setDate(String time){
            postTime = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_new_post_time);
            postTime.setText(time);
        }
        public void setUser(String user){
            username = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_new_post_username);
            username.setText(user);
        }
        public void getConstraintLayout(){
            postLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.post_layout);
        }


       //Here i wanted to sent the content of the post to my new activity so i can display it on my new activity but it is not working. 

        public void openPost(){

            int position = getAdapterPosition();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("content", postContent.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("time", postTime.getText().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OpenNewPostActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }


    }

}
```

And here is my Activity

```
public class OpenNewPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String postUserName, postTime, postContent;
    private TextView userName, time, content;
    private EditText comment;
    private String postId, currentUser;
    private ImageView addComment;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_post);

        initViews();
        intiClickListener();
        setPostContent();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        userName = findViewById(R.id.tv_open_new_post_username);
        time = findViewById(R.id.tv_open_new_post_time);
        content = findViewById(R.id.tv_open_new_post_text);
        addComment = findViewById(R.id.img_open_add_comment);
        comment = findViewById(R.id.et_open_comment);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        //Here i receive the post id, so i want to add the comments to the specific post.

        postId = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");

    }
    private void intiClickListener(){
        addComment.setOnClickListener(v -> addNewComment());
    }

    private void setPostContent(){

        // Here i replaced the content, but the textviews are not filled with the content of the post and I don't know why

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        postUserName = bundle.getString("username");
        postTime = bundle.getString("time");
        postContent = bundle.getString("content");

        userName.setText(postUserName);
        time.setText(postTime);
        content.setText(postContent);
    }
    private void addNewComment(){
        String newComment = comment.getText().toString();

        if(newComment.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte fügen Sie ein Kommentar hinzu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Map<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<>();
        commentMap.put("comment", newComment);
        commentMap.put("time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
        commentMap.put("user", currentUser);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + postId + "/Comments").add(commentMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
             if(task.isSuccessful()){
                 Toast.makeText(OpenNewPostActivity.this, "Kommentar wird hinzugefügt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 comment.setText("");
             }else{
                 Toast.makeText(OpenNewPostActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in all these lines of code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @Alex Mamo The intent with the Bundle doesn't send the data to my activity.  It doesn't work so it just displayed some empty textviews and I don't know why.
The comments are uploaded to the database in this case that isn't the problem.

Comment: @Alex Mamo maybe it is, because i have 2 Clicklistener in my Adapter class. So just the first "holder.view.setOnClickListener" is running?

Comment: Most likely it's because Firebase API is asynchronous. So any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the onComplete method, or be called from there, right?\